# Default sort for Xpages Dojo Data Grid not working on filtered values

Tags: sorting, filtering, xpages, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am trying to implement the DOJO data gird in my application. On load of the xPages I am getting the current user id in a session scope variable and filtering the REST services that supplies the data grid the data from a view, based on the user id. I have used the "keys" property to filter the values so that the current user should be able to see the values only relevant to him in the grid. This is working fine, but when I try to sort the results once the page is loaded it starts displaying blank values and sort does not work. I have made sure that the columns I require to sort are also made sorted for the back-end view by checking the "Click on column header to sort" option in the view. Still I am unable to get the sorting working for columns. Please let me know if there is a work-around for this problem or am I doing or not doing something for the default sort not to work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nash, I have had similar issues with the blank rows as you describe.  I think the blanks lines are rows that don't match the keys.  Here are my tips for fixing this.  The issue I think is not with your grid but your Rest service.

- Use a viewJsonService type of rest service
- Use a category filter instead of keys
- Make your category filter code similar to mine below.  This will ensure that you don't show documents to someone who shouldn't see them.  When the category is null, the Rest service will show all documents.  This isn't causing the blank lines, but is a best practice IMO.

  ```
   var category:String = lineItemBean.getThisUNID(); 
   //wherever your category comes from, maybe session.getUserName() in your case
   if(category == null){
       return "show nothing"
   } else {
      return lineItemBean.getThisUNID();
   }
  ```

I hope this helps.  My guess is that this will fix your sorting issues as well.

Comment: Hi Steve thanks for your tips, I am now able to do away with the blank rows after putting in the code as suggested by you in the category filter, but I am still not able to make the sorting work on the columns on the data-grid.

Comment: Nash, in my application sorting wasn't necessary where I used the grid.  I went ahead and tried to get column sorting working and I was unsuccessful.  If I make the columns sortable by column in the underlining view then the column sorting is disabled.  If I don't then it does nothing.  I think that this is not possible due to the categorized nature of the view.  As an example, if you go to the view in Notes, and click on a column then the categorization is broken.  I think you are going to have to ditch sorting or change your approach.  Maybe you should complete this question and ask another.

Comment: You are right. I had to change my approach completely. I could not use the dojo grid at all because of this simple sorting feature not working for it.